# Please change the color scheme of mobile site to red

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile

Currently, the mobile site of SFF.SE uses a blue theme, which looks like Super User desktop site color. Switching to red will match the desktop version of this site.

Comment: Doesn't every mobile SE site use the blue theme?

Comment: @alexwlchan Yes. Doesn’t that matter?

Comment: So do you really think we'd get special treatment here?

Comment: @alexwlchan Whynot? There's first time for everything. This is a feature request. If they care, they can do that to all other SE sites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I can’t speak for the SE Staff, but I would guess the answer is no.**

Quoting SE dev [Ebenezer Sklivvze on Meta.se question asking for something similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231442/226928):

> Declining as there are no plans to differentiate the sites on mobile (see e.g. the mobile apps).

Since Meta.se is much larger than SFF, and didn’t get an exception, I doubt we’d get one either.

Two additional comments:

- If I was replacing the blue on the mobile site with an SFF-specific colour, I wouldn’t pick red; I’d go for a more blueish-grey colour. Red is a highlight colour of the main site; not a main one.
- Last I heard, the SE Designers are already backed up for designs for meant-to-be-graduated sites. (e.g. Movies.se, which has been [ready to graduate for months with a design pending](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1471/9285)) Doing a custom mobile theme for every Stack probably isn’t high on the priority list.

Comment: This is bad. Hey SE guys, are you listening? This is a thing of few lines of code.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Even if it is “a few lines of code”, you then have to test it, catch all the edge cases, and do this for *every* Stack. I think it’s a tad insulting to imply that they’re lazy for not doing it.

Comment: @SachinShekhar (And that puts aside the issue of whether they even want to do this, which is by no means a certainty.)

Answer (score 1):

The color scheme of every site is the same, I don't see a need for making an exception for us. We'll get a custom color scheme if and when they start doling them out.